# Unbuntu 18.04 full disk does not boot

Tags: boot, ram, disk

I downloaded a docker file using sudo and the file filled my disk. Obviously I made a mistake. Now ubuntu does not boot. I only have a dark screen with a message saying :
"UBUNTU: clean 3232039/30883840 files, 11811580/125516160 blocks"

When I start it and press shift nothing happens. I created a usb key with ubuntu on it but nothing different happens when I start my computer with this usb key.

Do you have some ideas that could help me?

Best,
Tom

Comment: Ubuntu wont boot with no free disk space. You need to boot from a working Live Media USB. Mount the drive of the system with no space and free up some disk space. I would suggest delete the docker image.

Comment: In a side note Ubuntu 18.04 goes EOL at the end of May time to upgrade before standard support stops.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there something to do when I start my computer to boot with the live media usb? Because I used rufus and the tool available with ubuntu, I put ubuntu 16, 18 and 20 on the media device, I used two different usb keys and nothing happened when I start my computer.

Comment: My problem was that I had to press F12 to access my boot menu (because I have a Dell).

Comment: That is not a problem. Different computers have different ways o boot from a USB device.